# Converting raster to TIN and large section did not convert properly?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.0, 3d-analyst, tin

I've got a DEM for a pretty large area and I need to create a TIN. I'm using 3D Analyst Tools > Conversion > Raster to TIN. The process runs without any error messages, but a large section of the TIN is pretty wonky.

Here's how it looks:

[image]

Here's a more zoomed in pic:

[image]

The TIN looks pretty good aside from this gigantic area with covered in bizarre stripes. I don't see anything wrong with the DEM, so I'm pretty confused. The southeast area is a hill, so the elevation increase in that direction isn't an error.
Any clues? I'm pretty unfamiliar with TIN creation in ArcGIS 10.

Comment: I had a similar problem with a terrain in ArcGis 10. Is there a reason why you are using a TIN and not a Terrain? Perhaps raster to point then point to TIN (or better Terrain).

Comment: A trick to aid in verification of the original DEM is to create Slope and Hillshade rasters - these can often show up discrepancies which aren't immediately apparent when viewing the DEM

Comment: Thanks for your quick replies. I tried changing the Z factor slightly and it fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you may have reached the "Maximum Number of Points" limit.  By default this number is set to 1,500,000 but you can increase it.

(it is an option in the Raster to TIN) dialog